# How to retrieve values sent in post method in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

net I am trying to take a value from a previous form typically in php it would be written like this

```
$name= $_POST ["Username"];
$pass= $_POST ["Password"];
```

how can I write this in asp.net

Comment: What are you using asp.net webforms page? mvc controller ? http handler ?

Comment: that's asp.net mvc, so it's been asked and answered before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088450/simple-mvc3-question-how-to-retreive-form-values-from-httppost-dictionary-or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in web forms

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //access posted input as
    Request.Form["input1"]
    Request.Form["input2"]
    Request.Form["input3"]
}
```

in mvc

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult myaction(strig input1,strig input1,strig input1)
        { 
            //you can access your input here
            return View();
        }
```

or if you have view model for it, which is capable to take 3 inputs as

```
public class myViewmodleclass()
{
    public string input1{get;set;}
    public string input2{get;set;}
    public string input3{get;set;}
}
```

controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myaction(myViewmodleclass mymodelobject)
{ 
  //you can access your input here
  return View();
}
```

Comment: I guessed from your question, sorry if I misjudged.  you must watch these vdos to learn mvc http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro

Answer (score 1):

if you use GET

```
string usrnm = Request.QueryString["username"];
string pass = Request.QueryString["password"];
```

if you use POST

```
 string usrnm = Request.Form["username"];
 string pass = Request.Form["password"];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply I did that but it isnt working maybe there is something wrong with my query is this "SELECT first_name FROM Student WHERE username=@usrnm And password=@pass" Is this correct

Answer (score 0):

so you using mvc, which has a nice model binding.

So you are using mvc which has nice model binding. You can simply have a proper model object. For your example

```
public class LoginInfo()
{
    public string UserName{get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

in your controller

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Logon(LoginInfo loginInfo )
{
   // Do stuff with loginInfo
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your reply I am still trying to understand mvc  so may I ask in which file format should I save my controller and model and which of them is responsible for retrieving the values entered in the view