# A property that exposes post value in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc, in the controller I can access query string by

```
HttpContext.Request.QueryString
```

Similarly is there a property that exposes post data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a *FormCollection* parameter type via the Controller Action.

I just found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5088493/1139752

I suggest also reading up on the concept of model binding with a view of abstracting away the notion of Request.Form usage within your Action methods.