# create listener to http post request in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-4, fax, interfax

I have to receive 'call back' from interfax API. When a user (having account) on interfax receives a fax, it gives a call back to the account holder on a specified URL that must be able to receive Http Post request.
The guidance is here [Accepting incoming fax notifications by callback](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/rest/dev-guide/2985).

I created a a controller and action "Index" as

```
public string Index()
    {
        try
        {
            Ifax ifax = new Fax();
            ifax.UserId = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["userId"]);
            ifax.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            ---
            ---
            ifax.Save()
         }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //handle exception
}
    //Just saving to db 'true' or 'false', to know if callback receive.
    //SaveFlag();
}
```

When I receive fax in my interfax account, I get call back on my webserver.
But the problem is that I am not getting data. I get every variable null or empty.
Am I using a correct way to receive http post request from any client api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand Interfax sends a Post request to your application.
since its a post request you should be able to read posted values  `Request["phoneNumber"]`

[How to retrieve form values from HTTPPOST, dictionary or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088450/simple-mvc3-question-how-to-retreive-form-values-from-httppost-dictionary-or)

Comment: Thanks @adt,
it resolved my issue.
The difference was, instead of Request.QueryString["id"], Request["id"] worked for me.