# Ajax post doesn't pass any data to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Merchant/SaveDirty',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(dirtyItems),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                // get the result and do some magic with it
                //var message = data.Message;
                alert(ko.toJSON(dirtyItems));
            }
        });
```

...currently calls this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveDirty(string json)
{

}
```

...but when I hit the breakpoint in SaveDirty, no data is passed. I've verified that ko.toJSON(dirtyItems) returns a JSON string in the javascript. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: try data: {json: JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON(dirtyItems))}

Comment: Dave, this causes my MVC controller method to not get hit.

Comment: ok then try it just with the json.stringify section only

Comment: @Killingsworth, have you tried creating a C# object to model your items? Then your controller could just accept a list or array of these and MVC would handle the binding for you.

Comment: I could be wrong, as I've never used .net. However, from quick googling, it seems the parameter of the controller action is for GET variables? Just a thought.

Comment: @Bryan That's my plan; I wanna crawl before I walk though.

Comment: @DevinH. Where would you put the parameters in that case?

Comment: @DevinH. You can use parameters for either GET or POST.

Comment: please review the top 2 answers for examples of retrieving unbound values from the form: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088450/simple-mvc3-question-how-to-retreive-form-values-from-httppost-dictionary-or

Comment: Yeah, but there must be some way to post a straight JSON string to a controller action using AJAX.

Comment: Try this method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370062/posting-json-data-via-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-4-controller-action

Comment: `data: ko.toJSON(dirtyItems),` will return JSON (which is probably a complex object), but your action method parameter is `string`.  To test, replace `data: ko.toJSON(dirtyItems),` with `data: {json: 'some value'},` and check if value is bound in the action method

Comment: contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify(dirtyItems),

Comment: Did you try full URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KillingsWorth, is there any specific reason for which you are posting a JSON string? If not then, you could create a class corresponding to dirtyitems type and in your controller method you can accept a list of dirtyItems.

```
Class DirtyItem 
{ // dirty item properties }

[HttpPost]
public void SaveDirty(List<DirtyItem> dirtyItems)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following:

$.ajax({

```
        url: '/Merchant/SaveDirty',

        type: 'POST',

        dataType: 'json',

        data: JSON.stringify(dirtyItems),

        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        success: function (data) {
            ///
```

///

```
        }

    });
```

But if you are using knockout.js in your applicantion then you should do the following:

$.ajax({

```
        url: '/Merchant/SaveDirty',

        type: 'POST',

        dataType: 'json',

        data:JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(dirtyItems)),

        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        success: function (data) {

            // get the result and do some magic with it

            //var message = data.Message;

            alert(ko.toJSON(dirtyItems));


        }

    });
```

Comment: Something about "data: ko.toJSON(dirtyItems)" being changed to "data:JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(dirtyItems))" makes the ajax call not even hit my mvc controller.

Comment: are you getting any javascript error, (press ctrl+shift+j to check your js error) pls let me know

Comment: pls check the url from ajax request is correct or not, you can check it form your browser console, or provide a full url like "http://localhost/Merchant/SaveDirty" just for check, and see is it working?

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveDirty", "Merchant")'
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(dirtyItems),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                // get the result and do some magic with it
                //var message = data.Message;
                alert(ko.toJSON(dirtyItems));
            }
        });
```