# Posting files and model to controller in ASP.NET Core MVC6

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm migrating a project from ASP.NET RC1 to ASP.NET Core 1.0.

I have a view that allows users to upload one of more files, which I post using Jquery Ajax. I also serialize and post some settings within the same post.

The following all worked in RC1 (and pre-asp.net core):

Js:

```
    $('#submit').click(function () {      
        var postData = $('#fields :input').serializeArray();
        var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
        var files = fileSelect.files;

        var data = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append('file' + i, files[i]);
        }
        $.each(postData, function (key, input) {
            data.append(input.name, input.value);
        });
        var url = '/ajax/uploadfile';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');                   
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error'); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
  public IActionResult UploadFile(UploadFileModel model)
    {
        var result = new JsonResultData();
        try
        {
            if (Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                //etc
             }
        }
     }
```

**So the above does not work anymore, no file uploaded and no model bound**. 
I managed to fix half the issues so now I can get the model to bind with the following code. However, the controller will still give me an exception on the `Request.Files`. I added the 'headers' property, and I used `serializeObject` (custom method). In the controller I added `FromBody`.

Js:

```
 $('#submit').click(function () {      
        var postData = $('#fields :input').serializeArray();
        var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');
        var files = fileSelect.files;

        var data = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append('file' + i, files[i]);
        }
        $.each(postData, function (key, input) {
            data.append(input.name, input.value);
        });
        var url = '/ajax/uploadfile';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            data: serializeAndStingifyArray(data),
            success: function (result) {
                alert('success');                   
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error'); 
            }
        });
    });

    function serializeAndStingifyArray(array) {
    var o = {};
    var a = array;
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return JSON.stringify(o);
};
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFile([FromBody]UploadFileModel model)
    {
        var result = new JsonResultData();
        try
        {
            if (Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                //etc
             }
         }
       }
```

html:

```
    <div id="file-list">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="file-select" accept="application/pdf,application">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="file-select"           accept="application/pdf,application" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share how your `UploadFileModel` model looks like? and also how your multipart request looks like? (from browser dev tools)

Comment: In this case the uploadfile model only has one property which is the language setting (hidden field in the view). This binds fine, the problem seems to lie within the file sending, I added the html, I'm not really sure what info you're looking for regarding the request.

Comment: Your controller doesn't look quite correct, look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088450/how-to-retreive-form-values-from-httppost-dictionary-or) for a similar question.

Comment: @Frank what part is not correct? keep in mind that this is asp.net core not mvc 3 as the question you linked.

Comment: What is the exception you get when accessing `Request.Files`?

Comment: @user2713516 Does the FormData object "data" contain any key/value pairs when you make the ajax call? You could also get the file data by:             var i = 0;
            $(".file-select").each(function () {
                data.append('file' + i, $(this).val());
                i++;
            });

Comment: Why you don't use `HttpPostedFileBase` as `Collection`?

Comment: @user2713516 do you mind checking my answer?

Comment: I got it working using the selected answer below, please see my comment there. Thanks everyone for the input

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I started from this article which has some code that is almost the same as yours  [Upload Files In ASP.NET Core 1.0](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/f1cee257-378a-42c1-9f2f-075a3aed1d98.aspx) (see Ajax case).

That worked for me fine on 1.0.0, so I implemented your changes and what I saw is that it failed to send the files in the request (client side issue).

This is how the payload should look like when working ok using F12 in chrome: (not sure why the file contents are hidden by chrome).

[image: payload]

A little debugging and you are passing wrong data to `data.append`

The fix is in this line

```
        $(".file-select").each(function () { data.append($(this).val(), $(this).get(0).files[0]); i++; })
```

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (evt) {

        var data = new FormData();
        i = 0;

        $(".file-select").each(function () { data.append($(this).val(), $(this).get(0).files[0]); i++; })

        var postData = $('#fields :input');
        $.each(postData, function (key, input) {
            data.append(input.name, input.value);
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/uploadfile",     // <--- Double check this url.
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (message) {
                alert(message);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("There was error uploading files!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

No need to use `[FromBody]` or serializeArray()

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFilesAjax(MyViewModel xxx )
    {
```

This is my html, just in case:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="file-list">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="file-select" accept="application/pdf,application">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="file-select" accept="application/pdf,application" />
</div>
<div id="fields">
    <input type="text" name="Email" />
</div>

<input type="button"
        id="submit"
        value="Upload Selected Files" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah you're correct about passing wrong data to the FormData object "data", I noticed that as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I wasn't able to look at that particular project for a while. I tried your solution and I managed to get it to work using your code as a guideline. I did still need to apply serializeArray() on the $('#fields :input') selector in order to serialize the correct fields (e.g. the correct checkbox values and radiobtn values.) Anyway, you saved my day so thank you :)

Comment: Great post.  What about JsonResult?