# Add custom header to an iframe asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iframe

There is a legacy .net application. In its content page , I need to open a MVC application. So I am using Iframe and opening the MVC application .

I am stuck as to how to send parameters to the MVC application via custom headers. I cant use query string as the paramter need to be sent is quite big.

Pls help.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <iframe id="frame" ></iframe>
    </asp:Content>
```

THis is the piece of code in my .net application. How to add headers when MVC appl is being invoked.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'quite big'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you mean by passing data via "custom headers."  Typically headers are for metadata, not data.  If you have a significant amount of data to pass, the traditional way is via form/post.  Here's one way to do it:

In the legacy app (the one that contains the iFrame):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <iframe id="frame" src="https://MyLegacyApp.com/Handoff.aspx"></iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

Note: Yes, the SRC of the iFrame points to the legacy app, not the new MVC app.

Add a new page to the legacy app called `Handoff.aspx` that looks like this:

```
<!-- Provide image while form is posting.  Style = centered. -->
<IMG SRC="Spinner.png" ALT="Please wait" style="position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">

<!-- Hidden form that will post data to MVC site -->
<FORM Action="https://MyMVCApp.com/ReceiveHandoff" method="POST">
    <INPUT Name="Input1" Type="Hidden" Value="PLACE YOUR HUGE DATA HERE, OR IN SEVERAL HIDDEN TAGS IF YOU WANT.">
</FORM>

<!-- Script that autoposts the form -->
<SCRIPT>
    window.onload = function(){document.forms[0].submit();}
</SCRIPT>
```

Now the "ReceiveHandoff" page in your MVC site will be accessed via iFrame and initialized with the data passed in the form.  To read the data, you can use [one of these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088450/how-to-retreive-form-values-from-httppost-dictionary-or), for example:

```
var data = Request["Input1"];
```

Comment: I wanted to ask 1 more thing ..how to invoke a javascript function sitting in parent application from child iframe .

Comment: See [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe)